# memcached returns wrong walues

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

What could be the reason for memcached to return wrong value?

Ex: Key1 -> "abc"; key2 -> "123". 
When I am trying to retrieve data for Key1, data returned is 123 instead of abc.
This happens in my local environment(application on Windows machine with memcached-win64) and also in dev server(docker container with alphinelinux).

I am using memcached to store String value as Object in memcache in my Java application with spymemcached client version 2.9.1. In docker container I increased the size of memcached to 1024 MB from 512 MB but no luck.

This happens randomly and I am not sure when this happens.
If I clear the complete cache then everything works fine.

Did anyone face similar issue? If yes, how was this resolved?
It would be of great help if someone shed some light on this.

Comment: This has to be a code error wher you are inserting the key value incorrectly.
 Or accessing key2 even though you think you are accessing Key1. Size of  cache has nothing to do with the issue. I would sugest verifying the code wsorks as intended.